# Read car high temperature exhaust pressure sensor

Tags: sensors

Is it possible to read the exhaust gas pressure of a turbo car with an Arduino, and then control an electric motor based on the pressure?

Comment: Probably.  Might be simpler if you could either install a second sensor to use independently, or tap into the CAN or OBD and get the readings that way.  Finding specs on the sensor would be key; is there perhaps a group of car people who hack on those habitually?  Or re-apply them to model aircraft turbines or something like that?

Comment: Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I don't see why it wouldn't be possible.

You would need a sturdy barometer, preferably a digital I2C one because they are typically more accurate. I recently bought this one to measure altitude: [BMP180 Barometric Pressure/Temperature/Altitude Sensor- 5V ready](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1603).

Be careful about the temperature that the sensor will have to deal with, its maximum temperature is 85°C (185°F).

The motor, I'm assuming, would be fairly large so you would need a beefy motor driver that uses a 5 volt logic level, maybe like this one: [L298 Dual H-Bridge Motor Driver](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/L298-Dual-HBridge-Motor-Driver-p-284.html).

This is a fairly difficult project, I'd say mostly because of the difficulty you would have mounting the barometer and motor. Never the less, it still is possible.

Comment: I don't think the question is asking about replacing the sensor with something generic, but rather reading the sensor already present (or an additional similar one).  Generally, parts actually used on cars are a lot cheaper than generic functional equivalents, due to economies of scale in both manufacturing and distribution.

Comment: oh, The question was kind of vague.

Comment: Also using that adafruit sensor above would be a bad idea.  It was not designed to withstand the conditions around exhaust.  plus the dirt and oil.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at https://github.com/designer2k2/multidisplay they're doing exhaust gas pressure monitoring and a number of other things.

Comment: Although this answers the question, it will be useless if the link breaks. For that reason please edit your answer with a summary of key points so that the question is answered on this site. Users can then go to the link for more detailed information. Please edit your answer.